# Existing data in database SQLITE + Unity

Tags: sqlite, unity-game-engine

I need to check in the database if the value is current exist. but i don't know how   use data in my value  public Text CreateUsername.

```
    [SerializeField]
    private Text CreateUsername;
```

Create user query

```
public void CreateUser(string username, int status)
          {
              using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(Connection))
              {
                  dbConnection.Open();

                  using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
                  {
                      string insertuser = String.Format("insert into user_data (UserData_name, UserData_status) values (\"{0}\",\"{1}\")", username, status);

                      dbCmd.CommandText = insertuser;
                      dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                      dbConnection.Close();
                  }
              }
          }
```

Insert user query... in this process i don't know  what correct query will i use in where condition in String checkusername.

```
public void insertCreateUser()
    {
        using (IDbConnection dbConnection = new SqliteConnection(Connection))
        {
            dbConnection.Open();

            using (IDbCommand dbCmd = dbConnection.CreateCommand())
            {
                string checkusername = "select count(UserData_name) from user_data where UserData_name ";

                dbCmd.CommandText = updatestatus;
                dbCmd.ExecuteScalar();
                dbConnection.Close();
            }
        }
              ChangeStatus();
              int stat = 1;
              CreateUser(CreateUsername.text, stat);
    }
```

Comment: `string checkusername = String.Format("select count(UserData_name) from user_data where UserData_name = (\"{0}\")", CreateUsername.text);`

Comment: Thankyou @KashifSiddiqui its Working :)